# Mobx Reactjs is not working for me(I can't inject my store)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mobx, mobx-react

I am not sure what I am doing wrong but I keep getting errors. I guess will do one error at a time. I stripped down my project to the bare bones. Hope someone can see the problem

```
app.bundle.js?31044e2…:12841 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'isMobxInjector' of undefined
    at observer (app.bundle.js?31044e2…:12841)
    at Object.<anonymous> (app.bundle.js?31044e2…:35924)
    at __webpack_require__ (app.bundle.js?31044e2…:20)
    at Object.<anonymous> (app.bundle.js?31044e2…:23127)
    at __webpack_require__ (app.bundle.js?31044e2…:20)
    at Object.<anonymous> (app.bundle.js?31044e2…:17566)
    at __webpack_require__ (app.bundle.js?31044e2…:20)
    at module.exports (app.bundle.js?31044e2…:63)
    at app.bundle.js?31044e2…:66
```

app.js

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import stores from './stores';
import UserPage from './components/UserPage'
import { Provider  } from 'mobx-react';

ReactDOM.render(
    <Provider userStore={stores.userStore}>
        <UserPage  />
    </Provider>,      
       document.getElementById('root')
);
```

UserPage

```
    import React, { Component } from 'react'
    import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
    import { observer, inject } from 'mobx-react';
    import DevTools from 'mobx-react-devtools';

    import Asset from '../classes/user'


@inject('userStore')
@observer()
export default class UserPage extends Component {
    constructor() {
        super();
    }
    render() {
        let userStore = this.props.userStore;


        return (
            <div>
                test
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

UserStore

```
import {observable, computed, action} from 'mobx';


class UserStore {
    @observable users = []
    @observable activeUser = 2;
    @computed get count() {
        return this.users.length;
    }
    @action.bound setActiveUser(){
        // I would like to pass in a paramter but not sure if it is possible with @action.bound
        this.activeUser = 1;
    }
}

var userStore = new UserStore();

export default userStore;
```

index.js

```
import userStore from './userStore';

const stores = {
    userStore
}

export default stores;
```

User

```
import {observable} from 'mobx';

class User {
    @observable firstName
    @observable lastName

    constructor(firstName = '', asselastNametType = '') {
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = asselastNametType;
    }
}

export default User;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`observer` does not take any arguments. Change to this instead:

```
@inject('userStore')
@observer
export default class UserPage extends Component {
  render() {
    let userStore = this.props.userStore;
    return <div> test </div>
  }
}
```